# kernel HZ to 10000

Tags: kernel, clock

I wanted to build the linux kernel with some extra packages. For that I had to change the kernel HZ to 1000 from the make menuconfig.

I wanted to know if we can still keep increasing it to 10000 HZ or what is the maximum limit? Can someone tell me how to do that manually? Is there something else that I need to consider while doing this?

Comment: One question... why?

Comment: I wanted to apply specific delay to packets with resolution under 1 ms. But with 1000 Hz the maximum resolution was only 1ms

Answer (score 0):

https://passthroughpo.st/config_hz-how-does-it-affect-kvm/

> The kernel source includes options for 100Hz, 250Hz, 300Hz, and
> 1000Hz.

If you look the values of `CONFIG_HZ` in the `.config` file you can see the available options:

```
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_300 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_500=y
# CONFIG_HZ_1000 is not set
CONFIG_HZ=500
```